# Using a set instead of a heap? Which is the 'better' solution? [maximum cpu load question]

Tags: python, data-structures, set, heap

Here is the code challenge:

> We are given a list of Jobs. Each job has a Start time, an End time, and a CPU load when it is running. Our goal is to find the **maximum CPU load** at any time if all the **jobs are running on the same machine**.
>
> #### Example 1:
>
> **Jobs:** `[[1,3,3], [2,5,4], [7,9,6]]`
> **Output:** `7`
> **Explanation:** Since [1,4,3] and [2,5,4] overlap, their maximum CPU load (3+4=7) will be when both the jobs are running at the same time i.e., during the time interval (2,4).
>
> #### Example 2:
>
> **Jobs:** `[[6,7,10], [2,4,11], [8,12,15]]`
> **Output:** `15`
> **Explanation:** None of the jobs overlap, therefore we will take the maximum load of any job which is 15.
>
> #### Example 3:
>
> **Jobs:** `[[1,4,2], [2,4,1], [3,6,5]]`
> **Output:** `8`
> **Explanation:** Maximum CPU load will be 8 as all jobs overlap during the time interval [3,4].

A solution that is given, uses heaps:

```
from heapq import heappush, heappop

class job:
    def __init__(self, start, end, cpu_load):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.cpu_load = cpu_load

    def __lt__(self, other):
        # min heap based on job.end 
        return self.end < other.end

def find_max_cpu_load(jobs):
    # sort the jobs by start time 
    jobs.sort(key=lambda x: x.start)
    max_cpu_load, current_cpu_load = 0, 0
    min_heap = []
    
    for j in jobs:
        # remove all the jobs that have ended 
        while(len(min_heap) > 0 and j.start >= min_heap[0].end):
            current_cpu_load -= min_heap[0].cpu_load
            heappop(min_heap), 
        # add the current job into min_heap 
        heappush(min_heap, j) 
        current_cpu_load += j.cpu_load
        max_cpu_load = max(max_cpu_load, current_cpu_load) 
        return max_cpu_load
```

I just used a set instead (pardon the indentation!)-->

```
class job:
    def __init__(self, start, end, cpu_load):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.cpu_load = cpu_load

def find_max_cpu_load(jobs):
    all_vals = set()
    jobs.sort(key=lambda x: x.start)
    currmax = 0

    for j in range(len(jobs) - 1): 
        all_vals.add(jobs[j].cpu_load)
        if jobs[j+1].start <= jobs[j].end:
            currmax = jobs[j].cpu_load
        upper = min(jobs[j].end, jobs[j+1].end)
        while jobs[j+1].start <= upper:
            currmax += jobs[j + 1].cpu_load
            if j < len(jobs) - 1:
                j += 1
            if j == len(jobs) - 1:
                break
        all_vals.add(currmax) 

    all_vals.add(jobs[len(jobs) - 1].cpu_load)
    return max(all_vals)
```

Which method is better? Should I try to emulate their approach? Using heaps here just seemed unnecessary to me. What solution would be preferred in tech interviews?

Comment: Code should not be included as an image. Type the text. Also, your code has several indentation issues. Can you fix?

Answer (score 1):

> I just used a set instead

Your use of a `set` does not replace the logic that is based on a heap. That `set` just collects CPU loads with the purpose to extract their maximum. For that you don't need a set. You might as well use a list, or even just keep track of the maximum without such a data structure. So your code would return the same results if you would have made the following replacements:

| Your current code | alternative |
| --- | --- |
| `all_vals = set()` | `max_val = -1` |
| `all_vals.add(jobs[j].cpu_load)` | `max_val = max(max_val, jobs[j].cpu_load)` |
| `all_vals.add(currmax)` | `max_val = max(max_val, currmax)` |
| `all_vals.add(jobs[len(jobs) - 1].cpu_load)` | `max_val = max(max_val, jobs[len(jobs) - 1].cpu_load)` |
| `return max(all_vals)` | `return max_val` |

What you *actually* did to replace the heap logic, was to look ahead one job and take its end to define an `upper` and then iterate some of the next jobs.

> Which method is better?

That is the wrong question, as your solution gives the wrong results. You have not given a valid alternative.

Here are the results I get with your code:

| Input | Output | Expected output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `[[1,3,3], [2,5,4], [7,9,6]]` | 3 | 7 |
| `[[6,7,10], [2,4,11], [8,12,15]]` | 11 | 15 |
| `[[1,4,2], [2,4,1], [3,6,5]]` | 2 | 8 |

> What solution would be preferred in tech interviews?

You'd certainly make a good impression by coming up with the heap-based algorithm.

### Sort the events

This algorithm breaks the jobs into events. A start event will increase the current load, and an end event will decrease the load. We can build a list with single events with each having an event time and the change in load that happens at that moment. We can then iterate over this list in sorted order and keep a running sum of what the current load is. This will allow us to track what the maximum is:

```
def find_max_cpu_load3(jobs):
    # make a sorted list of events (time, load_change)
    events = [(j.start, j.cpu_load) for j in jobs] + [(j.end, -j.cpu_load) for j in jobs]
    events.sort()
    max_cpu_load, current_cpu_load = 0, 0

    for time, load_change in events:
        current_cpu_load += load_change
        max_cpu_load = max(max_cpu_load, current_cpu_load)
    return max_cpu_load
```